# Check out Codidact, an open source, community oriented variant of Stack Exchange

Tags: discussion, codidact

I have proposed a philosophy site for Codidact here: https://proposals.codidact.com/posts/290730

I encourage contributors here to also join there as it gives people the freedom to try out new kinds of site policies and site design. Codidact and Philsophy SE can exist side by side and benefit each other since each has different characteristics and the users learn valuable things about what a QA site can be like from both of them.